# Highly strange error in Angular application

Tags: angularjs, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I have a SQL Server database and an Asp.net web api for my web service.

I have below UI for adding a category

[image]

I have below UI for adding a expense in that category

[image]

After I login into the application.

**Category:**

I am creating a category which is getting created and in the database there is a record. Refreshing the page it displays the category. After logging out and logging in again the category is not displayed here.

**Expense :**

When I create a new expense, it is not displayed at all. But the created category is taken into the drop down but not displayed as in the screenshot above.

Code as below

Inserting my expense

```
$scope.insertExpense = function () {
                    var ExpenseObj = {
                        "AmountSpent": $scope.amountspent,
                        "DateofExpense": $scope.datevalue,
                        "UserID": $rootScope.id,
                        "CategoryID": $scope.selectedcategory.Id
                    };
                    appResources.expenseResource.save(ExpenseObj, function () {
                        alert("Expense Added");
                    });
                }
```

I retrieve my category using

```
appResources.categoryResource.query(function (data) {
            $scope.Categories = data;
            console.log(data);
        });
```

I retrieve my category using

```
appResources.expenseResource.query(function (data) {
                    $scope.Expenses = data;
                    console.log(data);
                });
```

AppResources has only the webapi calling mechanism as

```
expenseManager.factory('appResources', function ($resource) {
        var baseURL = "http://localhost:8080"
        var registerResource = $resource(baseURL+'/api/Register/:id');
        var categoryResource = $resource(baseURL + '/api/Category/:id');
        var expenseResource = $resource(baseURL + '/api/Expense/:id');
        return {
            registerResource: registerResource,
            categoryResource: categoryResource,
            expenseResource: expenseResource
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you checked server log, anything is getting failed??

Comment: Nothing getting failed in server side. if there is a fail the data wouldn't be inserted, But data is available